# Yii2: Change page without reloading the page

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, pjax

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                                if($data) 
                                {
                                    foreach($data as $row)
                                        {
                                            echo 'company_name: ' . $row['company_name'] . ' client_code: ' . $row['client_code'] . '<br>';
                                        }
                                }
                            ?>
                        <?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Trying to change page without reloading the page, tried with **Pjax** but page still reloads. How to achieve this without page refresh?

Comment: please clear your question, what you want to do?

Comment: I have created panel in which I want to list all client_code and company_name in one page it will show 10 records. next 10 records will be on page 2, pagination is working fine but when even I clik on next page whole page gets reload, i don't want to reload whole page, only panel page should change.